# react-bootstrap-table-2 sortFunc is never called

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I am trying to customize the sort function for one of the columns of my table (which is a date format). According to the documentation, this should be straight-forward to do using `sortFunc`, but for some reason it isn't working.

**The column definition:**

```
{
  dataField: "dateOfBirth",
  text: "Date of birth",
  sort: true,
  sortCaret: sortCaret,
  //custom sorting function to parse dates
  sortFunc: (a, b, order, dataField, rowA, rowB) => {
    console.log("Sorting dates");
    if (order === 'asc') return a - b;
    else return b - a;
  },
  headerSortingClasses,
},
```

I know the sort function is not able to parse a date yet, but it isn't even called (I don't get any console output).

**The table definition:**

```
<BootstrapTable
   wrapperClasses="table-responsive"
   bordered={false}
   classes="table table-head-custom table-vertical-center overflow-hidden"
   bootstrap4
   remote
   keyField="id"
   data={entities === null ? [] : entities}
   columns={columns}
   defaultSorted={uiHelpers.defaultSorted}
   onTableChange={getHandlerTableChange(
     patientsUIProps.setQueryParams
   )}
   {...paginationTableProps}
>
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

I threw together a quick example based on your code: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-table-next-basic-example-forked-h5pn0?file=/src/index.js

`sortFunc` is called if you click on the "Date of birth" column, you can see the console output. If you want this done at start then you need to change `defaultSorted` to:

```
defaultSorted={[{ dataField: "dateOfBirth", order: "desc" }]}
```

`order` is up to you but has to be set.